Run VSCode task as another user
I'm running a simple script in a VSCode task like this:
.vscode/say_hello.sh:
echo Hello World, this is $(whoami)!

.vscode/tasks.yaml:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Say Hello",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/say_hello.sh"
      },
    ]
  }

When I run this task in VSCode normally I get the expected output: Hello World, this is monsdar!. But instead I'd like to run this script as a different user, let's call him bobby.
Some more detail about my environment:

Running VSCode on a Windows machine, connected via the "Remote: SSH" plugin to an Ubuntu 22.04 host
My user has sudo permissions
The user I'd like to turn into does not have sudo permissions

Is this possible? What's the most elegant way? At best I can put this task into my repository and other eligible users can run as that user as well. Perhaps even on a different machine.

maybe with "command": "sudo -u bobby ${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/say_hello.sh" ?
